# Possible to hide series but show value in legend for dygraphs?

Tags: charts, dygraphs

I'd like to hide a series from a dygraphs chart but show the value in the legend. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like I can do this as a workaround:

```
series: {
  'legendOnly1': {
    strokeWidth: 0
  },
  'legendOnly2': {
    strokeWidth: 0
  }
}
```

If there is a better or more official way of accomplishing this, that would be cool.

Comment: No, this is the best options

Comment: You can also add option `highlightCircleSize: 0`

Comment: I tried this but the scale is changed with the hidden values

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
series: {
        'S1' : {
            axis: 'y1'
             },

    'S2': {
                 axis: 'y2'
         },
        },                                                                    
visibility: [ true, false],
```